# Rabbitmq server drops connection when client takes more than 60 seconds to acknowledge a message

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am currently using EventingBasicConsumer from RabbitMQClient.dll C# client, we spawn a different thread to handle each message that is delivered to the consumer.

We encountered a strange behavior, the RabbitMQ server closes connections at 
times with the error `missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s`. Few moments later the client reports an error saying `Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Library, code=541`. I also see this error `client unexpectedly closed TCP connection` happening more frequently.

In some situations the clients may take more than 60 seconds to process one job request and this error happens under such conditions.

Is it required that a job be processed within 60 seconds ?, because for our process this can vary between 30 seconds to 5 minutes.

RabbitMQ server: 3.6.6
RabbitMQ.Client.dll (C# client): RabbitMQ.Client.4.1.1

Any insight into this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You most likely handle all messages inside `Received` handler, which blocks every other activity on channel (I suppose), including heatbeats. Try to handle messages asynchronously: in `Received` event handler put them in some queue (like ConcurrentQueue) and process that queue in another thread. When done with certain message - ACK it on the channel.

Comment: I currently do processing like that, but why would that block the channel. I have a prefetch of 100 and I see 100 threads being spawned by the handler. I also see one thread actively listening to RabbitMQ, shouldn't that be taking care of the heartbeat ?

Comment: Well that thought came to my mind from description of your issue, I did not verify this myself.

Comment: Tried changing to async yesterday, still getting this errors intermittently :(

Answer (score 4):

I used to run much longer jobs (minutes) with [EasyNetQ](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Subscribe). It's more high-level client that wraps `RabbitMQ.Client`.

For me, the reason of these errors is something like Evk wrote in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911948/rabbitmq-server-drops-connection-when-client-takes-more-than-60-seconds-to-ackno#comment75034601_43911948). I would try EasyNetQ as it [likely](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Subscribe#user-content-considerations-when-writing-the-subscribe-callback-delegate) has fetching of messages decoupled from the handling process.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the TTL timeout in RabbitMq both per queue and per message

```
IBasicProperties mqProps = model.CreateBasicProperties();
mqProps.ContentType = "text/plain";
mqProps.DeliveryMode = 2;
mqProps.Expiration = "300000" 

model.BasicPublish(exchangeName,
                   routingKey, mqProps,
                   messageBodyBytes);
```

Documentaion is at
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

But I think you're better off by rewriting it to Async pattern for the actual processing of the message.

This might give you inspiration for doing async message processing with RabbitMq

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42836/listen-to-multiple-rabbitmq-queue-by-task-and-process-the-message

And in this question there are quite allot of information too on async message consumption.

[multi-threading based RabbitMQ consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842880/multi-threading-based-rabbitmq-consumer/21847234#21847234)

Comment: Thanks for your response Archlight, but exactly increasing the TTL going to help me here ? Async pattern might help, I am yet to verify this. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: For an immediate pain relief increasing the TTL to over 5 minutes should stop you from getting the timeout. But I would absolutely recommend using Async

Comment: Is the heartbeat duration related to ttl ? I see that there is a way to increase heartbeat timeout as well. but that will also just postpone the issue.

Comment: Seems like this would not help, as TTL counts until the message [is delivered](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) to consumer.